# Using gitosis to specify permissions per branch?

Tags: git, gitosis, gitolite

With gitosis, is it possible to specify write permissions so that users can push freely to branches with their own name, but not merge with the master? E.g. $USER/test1 .. $USER/test5

This mean you could host just one repository per project, rather than hosting multiple repositories for the same project, specific to each user:

```
 project1-user1
 project1-user2
 project1-user3
 ...
 project5-user1
 project5-user2
 project5-user3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gitosis controls access to repositories, but not by branch or commit.  So you could put the master in a repo by itself which had read-only access and let users push their individual branches to another repo ( or one per user, as you say).  I haven't seen anyone extend gitosis for finer-grain control.

If you really need to restrict your users' access that much and you want to use Git, then perhaps you should only take patches by e-mail and keep your repo as read-only.

Comment: I forgot this question!  I've been using gitosis for over a year now and I've been really happy with it.

Answer (score 20):

The [Gitolite](http://sitaramc.blogspot.com/2009/08/gitolite-managing-multiple-git.html) project offers this functionality. It's a rewrite of Gitosis in Perl. Its code can be found [on github](http://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite)

When I first wrote this answer, it didn't support `gitweb` or `git-daemon` integration, but it does now.

Answer (score 3):

This script seems to do per branch access control:

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/update-hook-example.txt

Comment: That link is now out of date, as git docs are no longer hosted at kernel.org

Answer (score 0):

[Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) supports permission by branch or tag names quite well.

In the Pro GIT book, [this section](http://progit.org/book/ch4-8.html) explains in detail how to set it up and configure per branch access right. Search "Config File and Access Control Rules" within that page.