# Gitorious branch permissions

Tags: git, gitorious

Is it possible to set branch permissions with Gitorious? I would like to have different permissions for master than for other branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is NO.

Still if you want to set permissions using Gitorious, creating separate repositories is a option and can set permissions as desired on these repositories. Now it depends on you to implement either each repo per branch or as required.
Any thoughts are welcome.

Comment: Is that a Gitorious "problem" or it's not possible because of git arhitecture?

Comment: @redman I think that's due to git's philosophy. You don't need to grant anybode write acces to *your* repository. Anybody is free to `clone` your repository and work on his local copy. If he wants to get someting integrated in the original project, he might send you a patch or tell you to pull from him.

Comment: @GhostRider: answer to this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579714/using-gitosis-to-specify-permissions-per-branch) question says that Gitolite has per-branch and tag permissions... So you can get the same thing with Gitorious by making a clone and then sending a merge request?

Comment: If you don't want other people to see your private branches, don't push them to the repository.

In general, you shouldn't give push access to your public repository to anyone you don't have complete trust in.  If you want to integrate someone else's changes, you should pull from their repository.

Comment: yaa correct .. it's simple and explained cleary. you can go ahead with that :)