# git pull works only for master branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-pull, gitorious

Pulling any branch from any repository from a computer inside the git server's LAN works.
However, on any remote computer (not on the same LAN as the git server), pulling master from any repository works, but **pulling any other branch hangs**.

Environment:
 - Git server is gitorious running on ubuntu
 - I'm pulling from windows using msysgit and either command line or tortoisegit
 - The url used is of the form: `ssh://git@[my.domain]/[proj]/[repo.git]`

I know [gitorious does not support branch specific permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925173/gitorious-branch-permissions). Also the fact that within the LAN all the branches work must indicate something... what could it possibly be?!

**Update:**
I suspected the branch I'm trying to pull doesn't exist, so I tried pushing it. Here's the result:

```
git.exe push --progress  "origin" other_branch

To ssh://git@my.domain/proj/repo.git
! [rejected]        other_branch -> other_branch (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@my.domain/proj/repo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

funny that doesn't hang...

Comment: Just to eliminate the obvious (and I don't mean to be condescending), do other branches exist on the Git server?

Comment: @ap :) yes they do, see question update

Comment: What's the output from `git fetch origin` ?

Comment: @AndrewMyers fetch hangs as well. I might add that this is a new installation of gitorious on a new server. the fact that master branch works indicates that it's most probably configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

First check if the branch exist in the gitorious webview, or in the file system of your server.

if it exist, try 
`$git pull --rebase origin other_branch` then
`$git push origin other_branch`