# git prevent user access to master branch

Tags: git, repository, policy

In gitosis, I have DEV, STAGING, MASTER branches. How do I restrict users such only admin can check-in or merge to master & test branches. Developers can only check-in to DEV branch. Developers can checkout/pull from master but not check-in/push.

Comment: please comment if you downvote this so I can correct myself

Comment: Gitosis does not support per-branch permissions. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579714/using-gitosis-to-specify-permissions-per-branch) provides more details, along with an update hook script, and the Gitolite recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

[Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) is one possible solution.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: And this is why I was originally thinking I should just leave that as a comment... I'm not about to copy the installation steps for Gitolite into the answer. The 'essential part' of my answer is "gitolite", not the page it's linked to. If Gitolite moves off of GitHub, or GitHub changes their slugs, and someone coming across this post is unable to understand my answer without the link, they're beyond helping.

Comment: @cjc343 I am using gitosis. the link you shared says for github, these procedure is also valid for gitosis?

Comment: The mention of GitHub is about contacting the author, nothing else. None of this applies to gitosis which is different from gitolite, and afaik does not offer per-branch granularity.